# Remove full name from login window

Tags: macos, terminal, login, login-screen

[image]In Mountain Lion, my full name is displayed at the bottom of the log in menu. As I want to sell my computer, I was wondering if there is a way to hide this? (it's the only place that you can see it as it is not the user name, and I can't change it in Sharing preferences).

I called Apple support, they told me there's a way to do it via Terminal, but they wanted to charge me for that. I looked up online, but I can't find a way to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences** → **Security & Privacy** → **General** and uncheck **Show a message when the screen is locked**

Comment: It's not the user name what I want to change, and either the computer's name (at least the one showing up on Sharing preferences).
I'm tying to upload a picture for you.

Comment: @Matt Ah, I believe I know what you are referring to now—see my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Is this in the list of previously logged in users?

If you're selling your MacBook, you should consider re-installing the OS with a clean slate, rather than potentially leaving items behind.

You might find there's still a userid on the computer somewhere; you can remove it by running `sudo dscl` and then `ls /Local/Default/Users` to see if the username shows up there. `delete /Local/Default/Users/name` should get rid of it.

Comment: It's not a user or my computer's name…
I can't re'intall the OS because the guy who is about to buy it wants some software I have already installed.
I'm going to upload a picture of the login window.